# Is there a sesquipedalian word meaning "first and maybe last"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

As in "Welcome to the First And Maybe Last Vernal Equinox Quest". We are having an over-the-top egg hunt-like event at the office, which we may never want to do again. ;)

Comment: If you have an *over-the-top* egg hunt, then a *first-and-maybe-last* one will surely meet the ticket.

Comment: Upvote for using "sesquipedalian" -- one of my favorite words.

Comment: You mean sort of *unrepeatable* event?

Comment: +1 unrestrained joy at finding the recursive meaning of sesquipedalian, a word I have never heard of before :)

Comment: @Josh61, I mean that the occurrence of a second instance of this event is unknown.

Comment: "One-time-only" almost does the job, but it does definitely rule a second occurrence out of the question from the get go, rather than defining it as unlikely.

Comment: Sounds like you could call it "to be either  indefinitely cyclical, or a veritable **Hapax Legomenon** —depending how bacchanalian the inaugural eventuates."

Answer (score 3):

*[Idiosyncratic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idiosyncratic)*:

> adjective
>
> Relating to idiosyncrasy; peculiar or individual:
>
> ODO

*[Ultra-idiosyncratic](http://letterboxd.com/astoehr/film/histoires-du-cinema/)* from a film review by Andreas Stoehr:

> The experience of *Histoire(s) du cinéma* is not unlike browsing
>   YouTube—itself a form of algorithm-guided channel-surfing—except here
>   there's an ***ultra-idiosyncratic*** auteur presence shepherding you through
>   centuries of high and low culture.

Comment: Sorta *sesquipedalian* :-)